# Can't load page from iOS but can from laptop and Android devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ajax, frontend

Hey guys I'm currently building a site that request data from Twitch API via AJAX. The site loads perfectly on desktops and my Android phones. But somehow when I tried it out on my iPod Touch 5 and iPhone 5, it seems like the ajax request never stops, thus cannot append data to my page.
This is my site: https://aaazureee.github.io/twitch/
This is the body part of my HTML:

```html
<div class="cover-container">
  <h3 class="masthead-brand animated slideInDown"><i class="fa fa-twitch" aria-hidden="true"></i> My Twitch Streamer List</h3>
</div>

<div class="loading">
  <img alt="loading" src="https://i.imgur.com/WQESRkB.gif">
</div>
<div class="test">

  <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>

    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <p class="text-muted">A Twitch-API project by <a href="https://twitter.com/4headlul" target="_blank">@4headlul</a></p>

</div>
```

JS file:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var streamList = ["HSdogdog", "AdmiralBulldog", "vanNDota", "DreamLeague", "WubWoofWolf", "17uu", "lamperkat", "febbydoto", "Arteezy", "AmazHS", "Moonmeander", "WagamamaTV", "dotademon", "feardota", "esl_dota2", "monkeys_forever", "Dendi", "sheevergaming", "BigDaddy", "Draskyl", "Chessie", "FollowAkke", "bOne7", "attackerdota", "noobfromua", "egm", "qojqva", "alohadancetv", "pajkattdota", "dotastarladder_en", "barnyyy", "zai", "aui_2000", "universedota", "ppd", "fogged", "purgegamers", "meraclechamlotte", "7ckngmad", "miracle_doto", "puppey", "h4nn1", "420jenkins", "illidanstrdoto", "sumaildoto", "jeraxai", "grandgrant", "jeyodude", "bananaslamjamma", "yawar_", "merlinidota", "beyondthesummit", "s4", "stormspirittv", "synderen", "funn1k", "emperorpenguin83", "kano", "miserytheslayer", "reimudesu", "shigetora", "matumbaman", "era17", "sneykingdota", "siractionslacks", "moodota2", "dizzykitten", "sakurafrost225", "Rafis0", "odpixel", "d47biryu", "vampyrette", "w33haa", "blitzdota", "ritsugamer", "limmp", "himegurecia", "dotamajor", "babyknight", "ccncdota2", "khezzu", "lil_hardy", "angelsimosu", "vankhoahoang", "resolut1ontv", "blackdotatv", "sing_sing", "midone", "eternalenvyy", "dotacapitalist", "keemerah", "osu_HDHR", "mssdota", "epicenter_en1", "koushudota", "yapzordota", "moonducktv", "pikachama", "qSnake_", "stan_king", "dota2fata", "madaradota2", "braxton911", "cr1tdota", "mikah138", "evilgeniuses", "dotagasm", "official_niqua", "arise_3012", "nooneboss", "forev", "ramzesdoto", "aliastar", "bububu", "0timado0", "envybaer", "smashdota", "nurbika", "brinkdota", "canceldota", "qodota2", "day9tv", "zingle313", "kvhdota", "abed_dota", "ohaiyodota", "boris_dota", "gorgcc", "ltt98", "pgl_dota", "spare", "hfndota", "happystick", "itshafu", "thijshs", "qsnake", "lizzarddota2", "ek0p", "godot", "chainsito11", "freecodecamp"];
  var online = [];
  var offline = [];
  var k = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < streamList.length; i++) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + streamList[i] + "?client_id=rznf9ecq10bbcwe91n6hhnul3dbpg9",
        dataType: 'json'
      })
      .done(function(data) {
        if (data.stream !== null) {
          online[k++] = {
            channel: data.stream.channel.display_name,
            game: data.stream.game,
            title: data.stream.channel.status,
            viewer: data.stream.viewers,
            icon: data.stream.channel.logo
          };
        } else if (data.stream === null) {
          $.ajax({
              url: "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/" + streamList[i] + "?client_id=rznf9ecq10bbcwe91n6hhnul3dbpg9",
              dataType: 'json'
            })
            .done(function(data2) {
              offline.push({
                channel: data2.display_name,
                game: data2.game,
                title: data2.status,
                viewer: "Offline",
                icon: data2.logo
              });
            });
        }
      });
  }
  $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    $("table").addClass("animated fadeIn");
    $(".loading").detach();
    online.sort(function(a, b) {
      if (a.viewer > b.viewer) {
        return -1;
      } else if (a.viewer < b.viewer) {
        return 1;
      }
      return 0;
    });

    $("thead").append("<tr><th style='width:25%' class = 'channel'>Channel</th><th class = 'game' style = 'width:20%'>Game</th><th>Title</th><th style = 'width: 15%'>Viewers</th></tr>");

    for (var i = 0; i < online.length; i++) {
      if (online[i].icon !== null) {
        $(".table").append("<tr><td class='name'><img class ='icon' src ='" + online[i].icon + "'>" + online[i].channel + "</td><td>" + online[i].game + "</td><td>" + online[i].title + "</td><td><span id='red'></span> " + online[i].viewer + "</td></tr>");
      } else if (online[i].icon === null) {
        $(".table").append("<tr><td class='name'><img class ='icon' src='https://i.imgur.com/0C7WUis.png'>" + online[i].channel + "</td><td>" + online[i].game + "</td><td>" + online[i].title + "</td><td><span id='red'></span> " + online[i].viewer + "</td></tr>");
      }
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < offline.length; j++) {
      if (offline[j].icon !== null) {
        $(".table").append("<tr><td class='name' style='color:#B2ADBF'><img class ='icon-offline' src ='" + offline[j].icon + "'>" + offline[j].channel + "</td><td style='color:#B2ADBF'><em>" + offline[j].game + "</em></td><td style='color:#B2ADBF'>" + offline[j].title + "</td><td style='color:#B2ADBF'>" + offline[j].viewer + "</td></tr>");
      } else if (offline[j].icon === null) {
        $(".table").append("<tr><td class='name' style='color:#B2ADBF'><img class ='icon-offline' src='https://i.imgur.com/0C7WUis.png'>" + offline[j].channel + "</td><td style='color:#B2ADBF'><em>" + offline[j].game + "</em></td><td style='color:#B2ADBF'>" + offline[j].title + "</td><td style='color:#B2ADBF'>" + offline[j].viewer + "</td></tr>");
      }
    }

    $("tbody tr").click(function() {
      window.open("https://www.twitch.tv/" + $(this).find('td.name').text());
    });
  });


});
```

So basically on iOS, the #loading gif never disappears and no data loaded into the table, which I guess the ajax request never stops so it doesn't execute the code inside `$(document).ajaxStop()`

Can anyone help me with this issue? Is it just my device bugging around or the site is not working as intended?

Comment: have you tried on Mac to be able to debug the console?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not really used to using Mac. I'm a windows user and write my site basically using jquery. So to be able to debug on iOS devices, you need a Mac to show something similar to Chrome Dev on dekstop?

Comment: Usually the behaviour on safari and iOS is similar. by using Mac you can troubleshoot it easier using Safari then enable iOS emulation mode. You can do something like on chrome dev on that then.

Comment: Sadly I can't afford a Mac. Is there any other way around?